# Can I use an Interface as a property with Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have the following class which is a model for a database table:

```
public class User : IUser
{
    internal int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public ITest TestData { get; set; }
}
```

When I run `Update-Database` command, it throws an error:

> The property `User.TestData` is of an interface type (`ITest`). If it is a navigation property manually configure the relationship for this property by casting it to a mapped entity type

How and where can I manually configure the relationship for this property if I do not want the actual property to be a class?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43161458/the-property-is-of-an-interface-type-iformfile-mvc-core/43161520

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9805329/how-to-use-interface-properties-with-codefirst

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EF does not support interfaces, but you can deal with it this way. Take a look on this solution [How to use interface properties with CodeFirst](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9805329/how-to-use-interface-properties-with-codefirst)

Comment: Do note that this question is referring to entity framework core, NOT entity framework. Does the same apply there?

Comment: Oh, hi me 2+ years later. This is disappointing.... Anyone got info on this?